# How can I get the host name from a URL in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a URL like "www.google.com/aabc/xyz". How can I get host name from this? I used this code:

```
 my $referer = URI->new('www.google.com/aabc/xyz');
 my $host    = $referer->host; //compiler error
```

I'm getting error at the second line.

Comment: `^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?\b`

Comment: Try that on `some.awww.net`

Comment: less code is not a virtue. Your compiler doesn't care how many bytes you use.

Comment: my $referer = "https://pulsesecure.net/xyz/abc";
$referer = ^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?\b;
print $referer;                                                                                                I tried this but it seems im doing it the worong way! how can I upply here.

Comment: You should fill out the question with the task you are trying to perform. There might be better ways to get at the end goal.

Comment: Im trying to get host name from the refere.

Answer (score 2):

```
use URI;
use URI::Heuristic qw(uf_uristr);

my $referrer = URI->new( uf_uristr('www.google.com/aabc/xyz') );
print $referrer->host;
```

Comment: Perl is not recognizing use URI::Heuristic qw(uf_uristr); command //error

Comment: If you don't tell me what the error is, I can't help you.

Comment: 500 Internal Error


"An unexpected error was encountered while executing the CGI
Please contact the administrator. Status: 500 Internal Error Content-Type: text/html" This is the error. If I remove use "URI::Heuristic qw(uf_uristr);" Im not getting the error, but "->host" will give error.

Comment: CGI errors can be really hard to debug. In the case above, you could either check your error logs for more details or try running the script at the command line first to see what the actual error message is.  Or you could try including this line in your script `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);`  That might give you a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 1):

*The question changed significantly since my first answer, which I've deleted. With high enough rep you can see it.*

You have in the code (it's better to post complete programs):

```
my $referer = URI->new('www.google.com/aabc/xyz');
my $host    = $referer->host; //compiler error
```

You say that you're getting a compiler error, but it's really a runtime error:

```
Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::_generic"
```

When you made the new object, you gave [URI](http://www.metacpan.org/module/URI) a string. From that, it's going to guess what sort of URI it is. Since there's no scheme, such as `http://`, in front of it, it doesn't guess that it's that sort of URI. Instead, it falls back to a "generic" class [URI::_generic](http://www.metacpan.org/module/URI::_generic). By the underscore in its name and the fact there's no documentation for it, you may surmise it's not meant for you to know about.

But, here it is complaining. It thinks the URI is a path (and some other things). The part you recognize as the host it parses as a path:

```
use v5.10;

use URI;

my $referer = URI->new('www.google.com/aabc/xyz');
my $path    = $referer->path;

say "path is $path";
```

Now you see what it did:

```
 path is www.google.com/aabc/xyz
```

The generic URI doesn't know anything about a host, so when you call `host` on its object, it blows up. It would be nicer for it to return undef, perhaps, but that's not what it does.

[oanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406224/oalders) already has an [interesting answer that guesses for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514477/2766176) to fill in schemes when it thinks they might be missing, but there's another thing you can do. Before you call host, check that the object can respond to it:

```
use v5.10;

use URI;

my $url = 'www.google.com/aabc/xyz';
my $referer = URI->new( $url );

if( $referer->can( 'host' ) ) {
    say "Host is " . $referer->host;
    }
else {
    say "Weird hostless URL: $referer";
    }
```

Now your program shouldn't blow up for the same reason and you can look at the output to discover strings that you couldn't process.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -e "http://www.google.www.com/abc/xyz\nhttps://google.com\nwww.google.www.com"
http://www.google.www.com/abc/xyz
https://google.com
www.google.www.com

$ echo -e "http://www.google.www.com/abc/xyz\nhttps://google.com\nwww.google.www.com" | perl -pe "s/^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?//"
google.www.com/abc/xyz
google.com
google.www.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much simpler than above.

**CODE**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
     $_ =~ s/^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?\b//;
     print $_ ;
}

__DATA__
http://www.google.com/abc/xyz
https://google.com
www.google.com
```

**Results**

```
google.com/abc/xyz

google.com

google.com
```

Comment: The regex will cover a lot of cases, but there are modules which will cover the edge cases as well.  It really just depends on what you need.